# C#/.NET/Mono: Glyph/typeface info without WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, glyph, typeface

Is there any way to retrieve the same info available in [this class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface.aspx), but without relying on WPF? My app needs to run under Mono, which doesn't currently implement this.

(Ideally, the alternative should be portable and run under both MS.NET and Mono...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Mono.Cairo provides this information in a platform-independent fashion (well, not really, but it's portable).